# How select a given JDK in CentOS

Tags: java-8, java

I want update the java version in a CentOS machine,

Actually when I do java -version it gives me :

```
$java -version
java version "1.7.0_79"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.5.5.3.el6_6-x86_64 u79-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
```

I'm using the alternatives to configure which java interpreter should be used :

```
 sudo alternatives --config java
```

it gives me :

```
There are 3 programs which provide 'java'.

      Selection    Command
    -----------------------------------------------
    *  1           /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java
       2           /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java
     + 3           /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_91/bin/java

Enter to keep the current selection[+], or type selection number:
```

and I selected number 3 (which is the jdk1.8.0_91)

however when I redo java -version it still the openJDK 1.7 selected !!!

```
$java -version
java version "1.7.0_79"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.5.5.3.el6_6-x86_64 u79-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Use `ls -al /bin/java` check link target, the result should be `/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java` or alternatives is ineffective.

Comment: ls -la /usr/bin/java gives me /usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java ...

Comment: What's `/bin/java -version` result? 1.8.0_91?

Comment: java -version gives me "1.7.0_79"  and /usr/bin/java -version gives me -sh: /usr/bin/java: /lib/ld-linux.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory

Comment: You can create a new link for that. `sudo ln -s /etc/alternatives/java /usr/bin/java`

Comment: Or try `sudo update-alternatives --config java` instead.

Comment: sudo update-alternatives --config java : not worked

sudo ln -s /etc/alternatives/java /usr/bin/java : said : ln: creating symbolic link `/usr/bin/java': File exists

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114559/discussion-between-chien-ching-lee-and-taboubim).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run these command to check your configuration:

- `$ which java` and the result should be `/bin/java` or `/usr/bin/java`. Otherwise, check your environment profile (/etc/bashrc, /etc/profile, ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bashrc, etc.) and remove similar `export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.79.x86_64/jre"` declared.
- `$ ls -al /bin/java` or `$ ls -al /usr/bin/java` should be point to `/etc/alternatives/java` or alternatives will be ineffective.

Comment: yes, in /etc/profiles there was a line that forces the java_home to point to the openJDK7 :) .. I commented this line and restarted the machine and all is good .. thanks Chien Ching